# Firebase Chat Reverse Scrolling

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am creating an android chat app that retrieves the last 10 messages from Firebase when a chat screen is opened. When the user scrolls up (reverse scrolling), it should load the 10 messages above the last 10 that was initially loaded. I know how to implement infinite scrolling for loading items from top to bottom, but in this case I want to load from bottom to top. This is not a situation for reverse ordering because reverse ordering just means i'd have to load all the messages at once and then reverse order them.

[image]

So as the image above shows, I want to load last 10 initially and then the 10 above the last 10 when user scrolls up and so on.

Comment: Did you figured it out? If yes, please show it here for others.

Comment: Any update on this?